# Can't display add-ons translation

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Add-ons (PloneArticle, ContentWellPortlets) translations for my Plone 4.2.1 don't work on my server (Debian 6). Works fine on my local OS X. Same buildout both, with UnifiedInstaller.

Comment: do `.mo` files exist in `(Installdir)/buildout-cache/eggs/(PackageName)/..../locales/` ? Oh, and does `which msgfmt` yield results?

Comment: See also http://vincentfretin.ecreall.com/articles/my-translation-doesnt-show-up-in-plone-4

Comment: @ Ulrich Good point. no .mo files. I thought they were generated when starting zope, according to http://vincentfretin.ecreall.com/articles/my-translation-doesnt-show-up-in-plone-4. Does not seems to work in my case. I Just wonder why ?  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @keul I was aware of that. Just starting zope should compile .po files, right ? Unfortunately not in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @jacquesseite if you have this envvar set: yes. If not: it's probably an OS permission issue (the user that run Zope instance can't write access folders where it should generate .mo)

Comment: @keul I will check that. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I actually precompile translation-files manually, allthough it's not recommended, it's a bullet-proof way (don't need to check the various factors like you have to do now), IMHO. Command is: `msgfmt -o filename.po filename.mo`

Comment: When you use the Unified Installer in production mode (root install), it sets permissions to that the Zope daemon cannot write into your Python packages. To handle Python and translation .po compiled files, the "precompiler" part is supposed to generate .pyc and .mo files. Make sure that's active.

Comment: @SteveM: Oh great, an explanation in one sentence, thanks! In converse, is it safe to say, one doesn't need to set env-vars in a dev-setup (no root-install, same user's running all processes)?

Comment: @SteveM: Allright, now I see, why you didn't answer, the "precompiler" part is *always* needed since Plone-4, just never noticed, using precompiled files :-)